# java.util.Objects.requireNonNull vs Preconditions.checkNotNull

Tags: java, guava

The documentation for [Guava Preconditions](https://web.archive.org/web/20160111154433/https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) notes:

> Projects which use `com.google.common` should generally avoid the use of
>   `Objects.requireNonNull(Object)`. Instead, use whichever of
>   `checkNotNull(Object)` or `Verify.verifyNotNull(Object)` is appropriate to
>   the situation. (The same goes for the message-accepting overloads.)

Can someone explain the rationale for this suggestion?

Is it for the purpose of consistency or is there something fundamentally wrong with the implementation of `Objects.requireNonNull`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's just for consistency.  The implementations are the same.

Comment: Straight from the source.  Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

Although from the example in the question it seems that OP is asking specifically about the particular form of `checkNotNull`, there is one more subtle difference in general in favor of using `checkNotNull` which is reflected in the `printf` style varargs form. For example using `Guava Preconditions` you can do following:

```
public void getInput(String companyName) {
   String context = "Google";
   String moreContext = "Facebook";
   checkNotNull(companyName, "Why not try %s or %s", context, moreContext);
}
```

with `Objects.requireNonNull` you will have to do something like

```
public void getInput(String companyName) {
   String context = "Google";
   String moreContext = "Facebook";
   requireNonNull(companyName, "Why not try " + context + " or " + moreContext);
}
```

Reference: See bottom section of [Preconditions Explained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained)

> Simple, varargs "printf-style" exception messages. (This advantage is also why we recommend continuing to use checkNotNull over Objects.requireNonNull introduced in JDK 7.)

EDIT:
One thing to note though is that all args to the errorMessageTemplate are converted to String using `String.valueOf(arg)` so you can use only %s and not other type specifiers like %d or %f etc.

Comment: This is a solid addition and should absolutely be considered when picking Guava preconditions over Java's `requireNotNull` as well.